# Как перевести Spring XML конфиг в Java конфиг?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, config

Есть такой бин, в xml конфиге

```
<bean id="initContext" class="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
<bean id="dataSource" class="javax.sql.DataSource" 
                      factory-bean="initContext" 
                      factory-method="lookup">
        <constructor-arg value="java:comp/env/${datasourceName}"/>
</bean>
```

Как этот бин сконфигурировать с помощью Java конфига?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Value("${datasourceName}")
private String datasourceName;  

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws Exception {
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    return (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/"+datasourceName);
}
```